# Create dictionary from JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a JSON file that looks like the one below. How do I create separate lists for gas, pm1, pm10, etc... using list comprehensions?

```
{
    'e00fce6866b13164840961dcdata': {
        '-MVId33W0ApTBDg1YtzV': {
            'gas': 52.7,
            'pm1': 0.1,
            'pm10': 0.1,
            'pm25': 0.1,
            'pr': 441.6,
            'rh': 14.6,
            'ta': 25.5,
            'ts': '2021-03-08T21:00:03Z'
        },
        '-MVIfE3Y2zWYzgrFefyr': {
            'gas': 52.7,
            'pm1': 0.1,
            'pm10': 0.2,
            'pm25': 0.2,
            'pr': 451.8,
            'rh': 14.1,
            'ta': 25,
            'ts': '2021-03-08T21:10:02Z'
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to match your request

Answer (score -1):

Use the module "json" and the function loads to open a json file content to a dictionnary:

```
from json import loads
path = "my/path/to.json"
file = open(path, "r")
content = file.read().replace("'", '"')
dict1 = loads(content )
print(dictionnary)
```

Then you can use your dict using dist of list to store informations

```
datas = {}

for i1, key1 in enumerate(dict1):
    print("key1: " + str(key1))
    dict2 = dict1[key1]
    for i2, key2 in enumerate(dict2):
        print("key2: " + str(key2))
        dict3 = dict2[key2]
        for i3, key3 in enumerate(dict3):
            print("key3: " + str(key3))
            value = dict3[key3]
            if not key3 in datas:
                datas[key3] = [value]
            else:
                datas[key3].append(value)
            
print("datas: " + str(datas))
```

here is the result:

```
datas: {'gas': [52.7, 52.7], 'pm1': [0.1, 0.1], 'pm10': [0.1, 0.2], 'pm25': [0.1, 0.2], 'pr': [441.6, 451.8], 'rh': [14.6, 14.1], 'ta': [25.5, 25], 'ts': ['2021-03-08T21:00:03Z', '2021-03-08T21:10:02Z']}
```